# When my Cocos2d game resumes from the background, animation actions stutter

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

I have a sprite that I am rotating on a menu screen in my Cocos2d game like this:

```
CCAction* action = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                         [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1.0 angle:90.0f]];
[sprite runAction:action];
```

The problem occurs when I send the game to the background, and then resume the game. If the send to background / resume operation is quick there is a slight glitch. The longer the game stays in the background, the longer the sprite will "twitch" when the game resumes, before it will begin rotating normally again. I am on Cocos2d 2.0, Xcode 4.5, running on iOS 6.

Edit: Good point Gangcil! Here is what I had (it was, I believe, from the Cocos2d boilerplate:

```
// getting a call, pause the game
-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [_navController visibleViewController] == _director )
        [_director pause];
}

// call got rejected
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [_navController visibleViewController] == _director )
        [_director resume];
}
```

I was able to get the problem to go away by changing these functions to:

```
// getting a call, pause the game
-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [_navController visibleViewController] == _director )
    {
        [_director stopAnimation];
        [_director pause];
    }
}

// call got rejected
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [_navController visibleViewController] == _director )
    {
        [_director stopAnimation];
        [_director resume];
        [_director startAnimation];
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this was the correct approach or not - there is a slight hesitation at first (understandably), but then the animation commences smoothly. The slight hesitation is better than the wild jittering that I saw before - but I don't know if this solution can be improved on.

Comment: It will be great if you let us see both applicationWillResignActive and  applicationDidBecomeActive methods